# Laravel Controller does not exist error while using fetch api

Tags: laravel, controller

```
Route::get('/biller- 
info','MyDomain\Http\Controllers\BillPaymentController@getBillerInfo');
```

All other routes for api are created like this.

Getting exception Target class [Mydomain\Http\Controllers\BillPaymentController] does not exist.

guzzlehttps is installed.

route - 127.0.0.1/biller-info

path - api > packages > mydomain-shop > src > Http > Controllers > BillPaymentController.php

BillPaymentController.php

```
 <?php

 namespace MyDomain\Http\Controllers;

  use Exception;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use MyDomain\Enums\Permission;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use MyDomain\Exceptions\MyDomainException;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;


  class BillPaymentController extends CoreController

    {

      public function getBillerInfo()

      {
       $response = Http::get('https://reqres.in/api/products/3');
       dd($response->collect());
      }

     }
```

Comment: Where is the file located ? normally the namespace is `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: path - api > packages > mydomain-shop > src > http > controller > BillPaymentController.php.....all other controllers are using that same namespace

Comment: Note that the folder names are case sensitive and have to match the namespace : `Http` `Controllers`

Comment: double checked no issues there

Comment: Try looking for something like this in your `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` file: 

`protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';`

Make sure it's not commented out, and try to change the namespace value to the root location of your Controllers.

Comment: still not working.....all other controllers are using that namespace and they are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading configuration files and clearing cache did the TRICK!!

```
          composer dump-autoload
          php artisan route:clear
```